# convert JPA project to java project eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa

I had to configure a 'JavaMysqlConnectorApp' project to JPA project on Eclipse. 
But when I revert changes manually to back earlier project on Eclipse, it shows error icon on project explorer.

Please find two image links where shows detail about problem.

[Here is error icon on project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCnjh.png)

[Eclipse bottom 'problem' tab shows why error icon showing on Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Sdjs.png)

How to convert jpa project  to normal java project(without JPA) on Eclipse?

Thanks in advance to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I find the way...

Followed the following steps to back java project from JPA project :

- click to the project properties
- find the 'Project Facets' bellow 'Maven' on left side of the properties window.
- unchecked the 'JPA' on project facet ( **I don't need JPA in mine project anymore** )
- save all changes

Then cleaning project and find no more error icon on mine project.

[This link shows you the lucid view !](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuQmk.png)

Cheers. Thanks to all for your valuable suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

One click away.

On the top right corner you can easily choose perspectives, just choose any other than JPA.

I'm not in front of Eclipse now, but if i recall correctly there should also be a context menu on project right click, named "JavaEE Tools" where you can permanently turn off JPA on this project.

Comment: Thanks man for your answer.